# cannot be attached to this EntityContainer because it is already attached to another EntityContainer. Lightswitch Update a collection automatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

```
 partial void updateRecords_Execute()
    {
        // Write your code here.

        using (var tempWorkspace = new DataWorkspace())
        {
            Saving NewSavings = tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.Savings.AddNew();

            var koo = from a in FromMainCompanies
                      select a;





            foreach (var i in koo)
                {


                    if (i.Member != null)
                    {
                        NewSavings.CaptureDate = DateTime.Now;
                        NewSavings.Amount = i.Member.Savings.Select(a => a.Amount).FirstOrDefault();
                        NewSavings.FinancialYear = tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.FinancialYears.FirstOrDefault();
                        NewSavings.Member = i.Member;
                        NewSavings.NewSavingsAmount = i.Member.Savings.Select(a => a.NewSavingsAmount).FirstOrDefault();

                        try
                        {
                            tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.SaveChanges();

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            this.ShowMessageBox(e.Message);
                        }   
                    }



                }





        }
```

}

Am trying to update records automatically in Lightswitch and I am getting the following error:

**Entity 'Member : 6' cannot be attached to this EntityContainer because it is already attached to another EntityContainer.**

I have the following tables, Member(s), Reconcilliation(s), FromMainCompany, ToMainCompany & Saving(s). Member is related to Savings i.e. A member has savings. And Member is also related FromMainCompany (FromMainCompany is a collection of Members and their total salary account deduction - *NOT that important*)

I have a button in my Reconcilliation screen called UpdateRecords *(which has the code above on its Execute() method)* that I want when clicked to add Member monthly savings automatically to all the Members Saving table but now I get this error - **Entity 'Member : 6' cannot be attached to this EntityContainer because it is already attached to another EntityContainer.**

-Thanks.

Comment: There is a relevant question in here - but please try to format the question to be a bit more readable first.

Comment: Sorry about that, when the update button is clicked monthly savings should be added automitically but I get the error:Entity 'Member : 6' cannot be attached to this EntityContainer because it is already attached to another EntityContainer.

Comment: I believe .SaveChanges is asynchronous. So you are attempting to do many .SaveChanges on the same entitycontainter. You should do the .SaveChanges after the foreach loop.

Comment: Yes, absolutely the SaveChanges method should be called from outside the loop, definitely not from inside it. I also see that you reference i.Member.Savings, without having ever set i.Member, from what I can see in the code you've provided. However, I'd expect a null reference exception, not the one you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Oliver & Yann, now am getting a null reference exception for the Member, Yann any idea of how i will be able to set Member from the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
partial void updateRecords_Execute()
    {
        // Write your code here.

        using (var tempWorkspace = new DataWorkspace())
        {
            var mymembers = tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.Members;
            //var myscreen = this.Reconcilliations1.SelectedItem.FromMainCompanies.Where(a => a.Member != null).Select(b => b.Member);
            //Member myMember = new Member();
            foreach (Member item in mymembers)
            {
            Saving NewSavings = tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.Savings.AddNew();

            ////var koo = from a in FromMainCompanies
            ////          select a.Member;


                NewSavings.CaptureDate = DateTime.Now;
                NewSavings.Amount = item.Savings.Select(a=>a.Amount).LastOrDefault();
                NewSavings.FinancialYear = tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.FinancialYears.FirstOrDefault();
                NewSavings.Member = item;
                NewSavings.NewSavingsAmount = item.Savings.Select(a=>a.NewSavingsAmount).LastOrDefault();
            }





            try
            {
                tempWorkspace.ApplicationData.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.ShowMessageBox(e.Message);
            } 

        }

        }
```

Figured it out, the AddNew() was supposed to be in the foreach loop. - cheers